# Why I can't use Enum Value in Public Const "Constant expression is required"

Tags: vb.net, enums, constants

I am trying to refer to a Enum from another class in my VB code. I am appending the Enum to the end of a string in the Constant. I then take the .ToString of the Enum.

When I research the error "Constant Expression is Required" I am lead to the MSDN page
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6707e415(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6707e415%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

In the page it states: "If the declaration is a Const statement, check to make sure the constant is ... an enumeration member..."

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Public Const c_sqlRStaffWithThePositionID As String = "SELECT GRA.* " + 
"FROM GRA_RS_AFF GRA " + "INNER JOIN GRA_DBUSER U ON U.id = GRA.ID " + 
"WHERE POSITION = @Position AND U.UserType <> " +     
Core.Access.UserType.AccessOnly.ToString
```

Comment: can we see the code?  part of what you say makes no sense `appending the Enum to the end of a string in the Constant`.  The code would clarify what you mean

Comment: _What am I doing wrong here?_  You are not posting any code.  If you're calling `ToString` then it is no longer a constant.  But post the code so we can help.

Comment: Public Const c_sqlRStaffWithThePositionID As String = "SELECT GRA.* " +
                                                               "FROM GRA_RS_AFF GRA " +
                                                               "INNER JOIN GRA_DBUSER U ON U.id = GRA.ID " +
                                                               "WHERE POSITION = @Position AND U.UserType <> " + Core.Access.UserType.AccessOnly.ToString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign the value of an Enum to a Const.

This won't work:

```
Public Enum FooBar
    Foo
    Bar
End Enum

Private Const Val As String = FooBar.Foo.ToString()
```

Just make the Const a Variable instead. This works:

```
Public Enum FooBar
    Foo
    Bar
End Enum

Private _val As String = FooBar.Foo.ToString '_val = "Foo"
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation. I guess I misunderstood the MSDN page

Comment: You can assign an enum value to a constant: Private Const Val As FooBar = FooBar.Foo.  You just can't do it the way the op was doing it.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I appreciate the clarification.